# Ubuntu 22.04.2 - Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, deluge

I know there is another answer, but that doesn't answer to my trouble.

**This link: [Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761773/requested-download-is-not-authorized-for-use-with-this-tracker) doesn't answer becase, at the time I'm writing - February 2023 - Ubuntu 22.04.2 is the LAST ONE version. That link referess to UNSUPPORTED OLD versions.**

I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.2 via Torrent but I have this error on my transmission: Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker

And there are not seeders or peers.

I'm using transmission 4.0.1 (via Docker) and this is the only one torrent with this problem.

Just tried with Deluge. Same thing. Downloaded file with so many peers, when finished tracker said Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761773/requested-download-is-not-authorized-for-use-with-this-tracker)

Comment: No, that link doesnt answer. Ubuntu 22.04.2 is the last one version, at the moment I'm writing this post.

Comment: So, Canonical publishes new Ubuntu version. Canonical publishes the tracker. The tracker say error. So, is it a fault Canonical side? Cannot use my imagination, other than swapping version numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The originator is correct,  there appears to be misconfiguration of the Ubuntu tracker.  If you visit this link - https://torrent.ubuntu.com/tracker_index - you can see that the tracker still has 22.04.1 versions of all the Ubuntu variants and not the 22.04.2 versions.

Comment: THIS is the answer! So, nobody knows somebody in Canonical to update that tracker? :)

Comment: Looks like the trackers have now been updated and now support 22.04.2.